# R - replacing strings using gsub()

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a lot of unclean data in the form:

```
abc  
abc/def  
abc/de  
abc/d
abc/def/i j k
abc/def/i
abc/def/i j
```

This is just the part of the data I would like to change. This is part of much bigger set of data.

I would like to change all the elements to `abc/def/i j k`. 
I have used the `gsub()` function as follows:

```
gsub('abc[a-z/]', 'abc/def/i j k', str)
```

**output** :

```
abc/def/i j k
abc/def/i j k/def
abc/def/i j k/de
abc/def/i j k/d
```

The problem being that it replaces any occurrence of the pattern.

The only solution where i got decent enough results are where i hard code all the possible options like this:

```
gsub('abc$|abc/d$|abc/de$|abc/def/i$', 'abc/def/i j k', str)
```

However, this would not work if there is a variation in any new data.
So I was wondering if it was possible to get the result without hard coding the parameters.

Comment: So, are `abc` / `def`  placeholders? Otherwise, `^abc[a-z/]*$` will work with `sub`.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want all elements to become "abc/def", so why don't you just use `rep("abc/def", length(str))`?

Comment: Try `sub("(abc)[/a-z]*", "\\1/def", x)` or `sub("^(abc)[/a-z]*$", "\\1/def", x)`

Comment: I tried the above suggestions. However, I'm getting results like `abc/def/de` and `abc/def/d`

Comment: Look [here](https://ideone.com/hpnyEZ).

Comment: @IaroslavDomin, I have other strings of the form `ijk/efg` etc. So, rep would replace all the strings whereas I only want the abc/.. strings to be affected.

Comment: Another variation: [`sub("^(abc)(?:/[^/]*)?$", "\\1/def", x)`](https://ideone.com/5pRyNr)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, It did not work for all cases. A few cases were missed. I cannot share the exact data so I used place holders such as 'abc' and 'def'.

Comment: You still can describe what these values consist of. You may even provide some fake strings that can better describe the string structure.

Comment: Let me edit the question and better describe the data.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please add `@` + username to let the SO user know of your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- c("abc", "abc/def","abc/de","abc/d","abc/def/i j k","abc/def/i","abc/def/i j")
sub("^(abc)(?:/[^/]*)?", "\\1/def", x)
## => [1] "abc/def"       "abc/def"       "abc/def"       "abc/def"      
##    [5] "abc/def/i j k" "abc/def/i"     "abc/def/i j"
```

See [R demo](https://ideone.com/5pRyNr)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(abc)` - Group 1: `abc`
- `(?:/[^/]*)?` - an optional group matching a sequence of:

  - `/`  - a `/`
  - `[^/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`